# Split CSV by unique columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv, pandas-groupby

I ran into a problem trying to split my CSV into the minimum value of CSV files so each has only unique ids in it

by running

```
count = df['id'].value_counts().max()
```

I already know the number of csv files I should create (file1, file2, file3, file4)

my expected out put should be

file1

```
 person_name     id    Total  Paid        Date          No
      Deniss  55227  1191,75  0,00  21/08/2019  15/06/2018
      RINALDS  56002   169,00  0,00  21/08/2019  15/06/2018
      OLGA  54689   812,90  0,00  21/08/2019  15/05/2018
```

file2

```
person_name     id    Total  Paid        Date          No
Deniss  55227  1191,75  0,00  21/08/2019    20180615
RINALDS  56002   169,00  0,00  21/08/2019    20180615
OLGA  54689   812,90  0,00  21/08/2019    20180515
```

file3

```
person_name     id    Total  Paid        Date          No
Deniss  55227  1191,75  0,00  21/08/2019    20180613
RINALDS  56002   169,00  0,00  21/08/2019    20180614
```

file4

```
person_name     id    Total  Paid        Date          No
Deniss  55227  1191,75  0,00  21/08/2019    20180612
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter Series and then write files in loop:

```
g = df.groupby('id').cumcount() + 1

for i, df in df.groupby(g):
    df.to_csv(f'file{i}.csv', index=False)
```

Test with sample data:

```
for i, df in df.groupby(g):
    print (df)

      person_name     id    Total  Paid        Date          No
    0      Deniss  55227  1191,75  0,00  21/08/2019  15/06/2018
    4     RINALDS  56002   169,00  0,00  21/08/2019  15/06/2018
    7        OLGA  54689   812,90  0,00  21/08/2019  15/05/2018
      person_name     id    Total  Paid        Date        No
    1      Deniss  55227  1191,75  0,00  21/08/2019  20180615
    5     RINALDS  56002   169,00  0,00  21/08/2019  20180615
    8        OLGA  54689   812,90  0,00  21/08/2019  20180515
      person_name     id    Total  Paid        Date        No
    2      Deniss  55227  1191,75  0,00  21/08/2019  20180613
    6     RINALDS  56002   169,00  0,00  21/08/2019  20180614
      person_name     id    Total  Paid        Date        No
    3      Deniss  55227  1191,75  0,00  21/08/2019  20180612
```